# Animate fadeIn on scroll from bottom up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet of code that makes it so when you scroll the page the site logo gets replaced with a smaller logo that persists at the top of the page, however I'd like to add animation of fadeIn where the smaller logo fades in from the bottom of the parent DIV and then fadesOut to bottom of DIV if you scroll back up.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 75) {
        $(".small-logo").fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $(".small-logo").stop().fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

Take A look here at the example I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/3cd06hef/4/

Comment: your fiddle seems to work fine .What is your question actually ?

Comment: I'd like to to actually fade in the .small-logo div from the bottom up, when you scroll, instead of just fading in.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that movement by playing with the top position [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cd06hef/1/)

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
        $(".small-logo").show().animate({top: '10px'}, 500);
    } else {
        $(".small-logo").stop().fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.small-logo {
     position: fixed;
    top:30px; 

    }
```

Comment: that doesn't work quiet right, it persists the small logo if you scroll back up. Take another look at my Fiddle which I have slightly modified so that you can see the effect better.